# The integral of $1/x$ from $n-1$ to $n$ is greater than $1/n$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I want to prove that $$\int_a^n \! 1/x \, \mathrm{d}x$$ where $a$ is $n-1$ is greater than $1/n$.
How to prove this? I know the integral equals to $$\log(n) - \log(n-1)$$ But how to proceed from here?

Comment: Draw a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to show:

$$\int_{n-1}^{n}\frac{1}{x}\ge\frac{1}{n}$$

which follows from the fact that $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing.